# Android activity taking button click of next activity?

Tags: android, button, click

I have three activities,Lets say A,B,C. I have a button in A. When we press the button in A loads button B. There is a button in activity B also.When we click this ,it will load C.Both buttons are in same position.

Now the problem is,When I click the button in A many times first it loads activity B then it loads C.How I can prevent this?
I disabled the button and enabled that in on resume.But that also didn't work.
What should I do?Can anyone please help...Navigation between first to secondactivity s too slow.I have camera api integration in second Activity.Is this is happening because of this?

```
public void onButtonAPressed(View v){
    final Intent sIntent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(sIntent);     
}
```

Comment: Please add a code snip for a better clarification

Comment: Code, post some code?

Comment: @Skynet which code should i post here?

Comment: Your XML and onCLick listeners

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing but, I'll clarify what I think you're asking.

I believe you're saying that you have views A, B and C. Each has a button in exactly the same point such that when you click A, it loads B. When you click the button in Activity B it loads C.

Your problem is that rapid clicking of the button in 'A' goes through to Activity 'B' and then causes 'C' to load.

Assuming that is correct:

I note from the above that after you are calling startActivity you are not closing your current activity with a 'finish()'. I presume the same is true for all your activities. If that is the case then I believe that you are potentially causing CPU or memory to be consumed unnecessarily. Additionally it could be a factor in the button press being so quickly consumed by 'B'.

What I'd thus suggest is:

`finish()` an activity when you load the next one.

Disable the button by default and cause it to be enabled after a small time duration perhaps. You can do this by using a handler.

```
private myButtonEnableHandler = new Handler();
```

In onCreate:

```
myButtonEnableHandler.postDelayed(buttonEnablerFunction, 1000);
```

Then create a buttonEnablerFunction to 'enable' the button. I believe that this should prevent the accidental click-thru.

Remember to destroy the handler in the onDestroy function (`myButtonEnableHandler.removeCallbacks(buttonEnablerFunction);`

Comment: thanks. but I need the activity in back. I disabled the button as soon i am getting a click. and i tried the second button will be visible only in onresume,then also it is not working

Comment: I think you'd then need to post more code. If the button is pressed then it will react with your code, if not, I can't see how that code is called unless something else is wrong, i.e. in the onCreate or onResume function. You thus need to share more code so we can help.